# Rigid body. Why doesn't the ball fall into the cone?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

When I try to simulate ball (active rigid body) falling into the cone (passive rigid body), the ball just doesn't fall into, but stays on the top (like there was a face, but I deleted it).

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and [**Add images**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) that might help us understand your scene and the settings you used on the rigid body.

Comment: Are you using "Mesh" instead of Convex Hull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Rigid Body Collisions set the Shape on the cone to **Mesh**

[image]

Comment: thank you, I changed it to mesh and it Works. I used Convex hull before. Thanks a lot